# How to correctly model noise?

Tags: time-series, self-study, normal-distribution, modeling, white-noise

Assume a linear mixing model $x = As$, where $x = (x_{0}, ..., x_{n})^T$ are linear mixtures of $s = (s_{0}, ..., s_{n})^T$, and $A$ is the mixing matrix.

Now, if I introduce additive noise to this system, that is,
$x = As + e$, where $e = (e_{0}, ..., e_{n})$, what are the relations between $e_{0}, ..., e_{n}$?

For example, assume I have three microphones ($x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}$) in a room. There are also three speakers ($s_0, s_1, s_2$) and some background noise ($e$). If we assume the noise is white gaussian (or laplacian, or uniform), and that the noise level is static over the room, do I get the same noise into each of the microphones, that is $e_0 = e_1 = e_2$? If not, why?

Comment: By definition, if you assume [additive white Gaussian noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise), $e_0$, $e_1$, and $e_2$ are independent and generally will not be equal. That is what the "white" in the "white noise" means, uncorrelated (independent for Gaussian noise) and mean zero.  You could choose to have the same noise for each speaker if that makes sense for your application (I wouldn't think it does though), but that would not be white noise.

Answer (score 2):

The error terms (e0, e1, e2) are independent.  They could have the same mean and variance (e.g., mean=0, sd=1, "white"), but are still independently generated.

The noise reaching the microphones could be the result of a variety of unknown processes --- each microphone could be at a different point in the room, some could be of higher quality than others, etc.  The background noise, "e", could be one of several factors influencing the departure of x from the model's process.  The line between observation error and process error can be fuzzy at times, but either way there are reasons why the series of error terms should be independent between your state (x) variables.

When I've done similar simulations, my error terms have been generated independently.